# How to add class in image markdown in Ghost?

Tags: markdown, ghost-blog

In Ghost, the markdown for image is

`![alt](src)`

Is there a hidden format for adding a class in the `img` tag? Or is this feature not in Ghost yet?

I wanted to have a result like this:

`<img src="src" alt="alt" class="img-thumbnail">`

I don't want to use the html markup. I really need to achieve this using markdown. Please help..

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In [plain markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) classes for images are not possible. In some implementations it is possible, e.g. [markdown extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/) uses `![alt](src) {.class}`.
I tried it, but in Ghost it is not possible, neither `![alt|img-thumbnail](src)`. Also no hints in the [doku](http://docs.ghost.org/usage/writing/).

**But you can use a workaround:**

If you use the `src` as css-attribute!

Just add an 'useless' hash to the URL:

`![alt](src#img-thumbnail)`

Then you can address this in CSS or JavaScript:

`img[src$='#img-thumbnail'] { float:left;}`

Comment: This awesome! However it does not seem to work with `pandoc` used with option `--self-contained`, that is when image gets embedded as a base64.

Comment: @Michał the useless hash works for me also with base64 https://jsfiddle.net/g6w2o91k/ , can you give me the code of your base64 image.

Comment: this is not even a hack, but a very elegant method. Wouldn´t have find out on my own, thanks !

Comment: Anyone looking to do this in Kramdown (Jekyll) will need to knock out the space between the src and class: `![alt](src){.class}`

Comment: FYI, this won't work in github's markdown.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261461/mix-github-markdown-language-with-css

Comment: THIS IS SOME KING ###! I was looking for a solution for this unsing vuepress.. but the plugins doesn't seems to work very well

Answer (score 3):

this is perhaps too obvious but you can put it in any element you wish i.e.

```
 <div class="myDiv">
    ![](...)
 </div>
```

and then use css inheritance

```
.myDiv img { width: 50px; }
```

since markup in ghost supports html (probably most do) you can also do regular <img...> tags as well

Answer (score 0):

in ghost the file post.hbs rendering de {{content}} whit class .kg-card-markdown
you can create this function for js add class in all image in post content

```
function imageResponsive() {
  $('.kg-card-markdown').each(function(){
    $('img').addClass('img-responsive');     
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ghost the file post.hbs rendering de {{content}} whit class .kg-card-markdown u can use css to whit sass

```
.kg-card-markdown { 
  img{
    @extend .img-responsive;
  } 
}
```

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help readers evaluate the answer for their situation.

Answer (score -6):

You can add them through jQuery with the following code before the body end tag on the default.hbs file

```
$('img').addClass('img-thumbnails');
```