# Add icon in alert-block in Jupyter notebook

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, markdown, alert

I would like to add a **warning** or **note** icon in an alert-block in `Jupyter notebook`. To create an alert-block in Jupyter notebook we could use the following code:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-info">
<b>Tip:</b> Use blue boxes (alert-info) for tips and notes. 
If it’s a note, you don’t have to include the word “Note”.
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Now I could like to add an icon. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544499/how-to-make-a-styled-markdown-admonition-box-in-a-github-gist) it is discussed to add icon in markdown in GitHub. We may use then the syntax `:warning:`. This unfortunately doesn't work in Jupyter notebook:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-info">
:warning: Use blue boxes (alert-info) for tips and notes. 
If it’s a note, you don’t have to include the word “Note”.
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see this doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add an icon to an alert-block in Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work, but that is only a representation of you needing to copy and paste the symbol, hence the '(just copy paste)' note [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57118885/8508004) where you indicated.

###### Edited version of your code for the markdown to be in the cells:

```markdown
> ⚠️ **If you are using mobile browser**: Be very careful here
```

```markdown
<div class="alert alert-block alert-info">
⚠️ Use blue boxes (alert-info) for tips and notes. 
If it’s a note, you don’t have to include the word “Note”.
</div>
```

###### Image of result:

[image]

---

Test **temporary** Jupyter session, with no login needed, provided via the MyBinder service from [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements).